# 'Partial boundedness' of continuously parametrised power series

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, power-series

Let $a_1, a_2, \ldots : D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of continuous functions, with $D$ a compact metric space.

Suppose that the function $f : D\times[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by

$$\tag{1}f(x,y) := \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i(x)\cdot y^i$$

exists and is such that its $y$-section $f_{y_0}:=f(\,\cdot,y_0)$ is bounded on $D$ for some $y_0>0$.

**Question:** Can we conclude that the sections $f_{y}$ are bounded on $D$ for any $y\geq y_0$?

If necessary, it may be assumed that the $a_i$ are all non-negative.

Comment: If you look at the one-dimensional case (i.e., where $D$ is a point), then you have a power series which converges on the positive real axis and so on the whole complex plane (to an entire function).  You wouldn't expect to extend any boundedness conditions at a given point to ones with larger absolute value.  However, you can use the Cauchy integral formula when you reduce it.  This applies in modified form to your case--you now have an entire function with values in $C(D)$ and Banach space valued function theory has been well established since the middle of the last century.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Indeed, let $D:=[0,1]$ and
\begin{equation}
    a_n(x):=nx\,1(x\le1/n)+(2-nx)1(1/n<x<2/n)
\end{equation}
for natural $n$ and $x\in D$.

Then $a_n$ is continuous for each $n$, the sum
\begin{equation}
    f(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(x)y^n
\end{equation}
has only finitely many nonzero summands for each $(x,y)\in D\times[0,\infty)$ and hence takes real values.
Also, $0\le a_n\le1$ and hence
\begin{equation}
    0\le f(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(x)y^i\le1
\end{equation}
for $y=1/2$. So, $f(\cdot,1/2)$ is bounded.

However, for any natural $k$ and $x=1/k$,
\begin{equation}
    f(x,2)\ge\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx\,1(x\le1/n)2^n\ge k(1/k)2^k\to\infty
\end{equation}
as $k\to\infty$. So, $f(\cdot,2)$ is unbounded.

---

Here is the graph $\Big\{\Big(x,\dfrac{f(x,2)}{2^{2/x}x}\Big)\colon10^{-3}\le x\le1\Big\}$:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take $D=[0,2]$, $a_i(x)=x^i$, then $f(x,1/3)$ converges for all $x\in D$, but $f(x,1)$ is unbounded as $x\to1$. So, unless I am misreading something in your question, the answer is negative.

**EDIT:** If we require that the series converges for all $x$ and $y$, the answer is still negative: let $x_i=1/2^i$ and $a_i(x)$ be the regular "hat" functions "centered" at $x_i$-s (see the illustration). Then (1) is $0$ for $x=0$ and a piecewise linear approximation to $x^{\log_{1/2}y}$ for $x>0$. The latter is bounded on $D=[0,1]$ for $y\leq1$ and unbounded for $y>1$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Iiro. Just from your example, it seems that the function $f$ you gave is not defined (divergent) on $[1,2]\times\{1\}\subset D\times\{1\}$, opposing the above requirement of existence?

Comment: What do you mean by defined then? If you wish to say that "defined" = "the series converges for all $(x,y)\in D\times [0,\infty)$" then your definition of "defined" guarantees your claim for any fixed $y$. Or are you asking if $f(x,y)$ is bounded for *all* $x$ and $y$, i.e., is globally bounded?

Comment: I think our definitions of "defined" are in line. What I would like to exclude are sections $f_y : D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which, although defined on all of $D$, are *unbounded* as functions on $D$ (say, exhibit a blow up towards the boundary of $D$).

Comment: That would not be possible if $D$ is compact, however...

Comment: Even though the $f_y$ are not necessarily continuous? I take it that 'blow-up pathologies' of this sort might eventually be prevented due to the continuity of the $a_i$ (given that $f$ 'exists' in our sense), but is this trivial to see? (Thanks for your patience!)

Comment: I was thinking along the lines that if you want your series (1) to be convergent for all $x$ and $y$, you must have $a_i(x)$ to be decaying super exponentially for any given $x$ and, as $D$ is compact, uniformly in $x$. But this would imply that the series would always be bounded.

Comment: Thank you, Iiro! Would you mind explaining in more detail/providing a reference on how (and in what sense) the compactness of $D$ implies the super-exponential decay of $a_i(x)$ to be 'uniform in $x$,' and how this would (in total) imply the boundedness of $f_y$ for each $y$? That would be very much appreciated (and be accepted as an answer)!

Comment: Nevermind: I added an example which shows that the answer is still negative even if the series converges for all $(x,y)$. It also shows that my "uniform decay" claim is incorrect :) however...